# Composite index in datastore-index.xml not created

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Here is my datastore-index file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
  <datastore-index kind="Stock" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="code" direction="asc" />
    <property name="endTime" direction="asc" />
  </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

The index entry was created exactly as suggested by App Engine in error log. 
I put the index file in folder webapp/WEB-INF.

Despite all my efforts, no index were necer displayed on the Datastore index page and when I query I get the same error message: no matching index found.

Could you help me?

Comment: what is the exact name of your datastore xml file?

Comment: In some cases updating the app itself doesn't automatically update the indexes. Try updating manually with `./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh update_indexes myapp/war`, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#updating_indexes

Comment: @MichaelMeyer, the name of my datastore file is datastore-indexes.xml

Comment: that seems to be ok. I am using the yaml file format for my indexes (index.yaml). Maybe you can try this

Comment: @Marcelino can you try it again - it should have worked.

Comment: My index.yaml file in the cloud reflects the changes on my datastore-indexes.xml, but GAE doesn`t criate the index... Anyway, I changed to Cloud SQL...